# Dynamically create Javascript mapping object on changing option of select box

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping

**I have two select boxes : section and chart.**

```
<select #section>
<option value="section 1">section 1</option>
<option value="section 2">section 2</option>
</select>
<select #chart>
<option value="graph">graph</option>
<option value="bar">bar</option>
<option value="donuts">donuts</option>
</select>
```

There is one button:

```
<button (click)="click()">Add</button>
```

I want to create dynamic java script object based on selection of the two mentioned select boxes.

The output shall look like the following

```
0: {section: section 1, chart: Array(1)}
1: {section: section 2, chart: Array(3)}

Array(1) = ['donuts']
```

since Add is clicked while donuts option is selected from second select box when section 1 is selected in first select box

```
Array(3) = ['donuts','bar','graph']
```

since Add is clicked after selecting each option from 2nd select box while section 2 is selected from 1st select box

Can someone help please?

```
<div class="toolbar">
        <select #section>
            <option value="section 1">section 1</option>
            <option value="section 2">section 2</option>
        </select>

        <select #chart>
                <option value="graph">graph</option>
                <option value="bar">bar</option>
                <option value="donuts">donuts</option>
            </select>
        <button (click)="click()">
            Add widget 
        </button>   `  



section : section 1
chart: Array(1)
```

Comment: Do you want to keep history of all options selected from 2nd select box till Add Widget is clicked?

Comment: chart history should be specific to the section selected.

Comment: like if section 1 is selected with 1 chart again section 2 is selected but again section 1 is selected with another chart option then section 1 chart history should be there

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [(ngModel)] to bind data

HTML as below:

```
<div class="toolbar">
    <select  [(ngModel)]="data.section">
        <option value="section 1">section 1</option>
        <option value="section 2">section 2</option>
    </select>

    <select  [(ngModel)]="data.chart">
            <option value="graph">graph</option>
            <option value="bar">bar</option>
            <option value="donuts">donuts</option>
        </select>
    <button (click)="click()">
        Add widget 
    </button>
    </div>
```

.ts file as:

```
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'stackoverflow';
  data: any;
  constructor() {
    this.data={
        "section":"",
        "chart":""
    }
  }

  click():void {
    console.log(this.data);
  }
}
```

Now when you select "section 2" from first select box and "bar" in second one then variable data will be '`{section: "section 2", chart: "bar"}`'.

Comment: i want to create an array of objects with 2 keys section and chart , the second key 'chart' should be an array which saves all history of the charts selected for that particular section. If the section is changed and a value is selected in the chart dropdown, then that value is again pushed in the array of the second key in the array 'chart'.